# Difference in rostopic hz and fps of a camera

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using turtlebot3 burger in which I'm using a rasp camera v2 attached to the Raspberry Pi with raspicam_node and a Host PC where I run my image processing nodes. Therefore, I need to transfer the captured raw images via wireless network.
I am experimenting with different resolutions and frame rates at the moment to find out which is the most effective way. However, I have a doubt about the way I validate my results. I am using rostopic hz in my raspberry pi to find out the publishing rate of the camera, which is around 35-40 FPS for 1280x720 and doing the same thing in my local pc in which I get very different results like 1-2 hz to 10-15 hz. I know that this might be about the network but my question is, when I get 1-2 hz as a result of rostopic hz, I launch rqt_image_view and somehow the displayed capture does not look like 1-2 FPS but higher. So I am wondering if there is a better way to validate regarding the frame rate I receive from the subscriber, other than rostopic hz.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354558/difference-in-rostopic-hz-and-fps-of-a-camera/) by [rosberrypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31252/rosberrypi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using `rostopic hz` should be accurate, both `rqt_image_view` and `rostopic hz` should be accessing the same data. You can also record the images to a [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) and look at the timestamps to get the exact timings if you don't believe it.

---

Originally posted by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) with karma: 464 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosberrypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31252/rosberrypi/) on 2020-06-12**:
That is indeed what I ended up doing yesterday, I think my hesitation was because I was not waiting a certain amount of time to understand the average of the results coming from rostopic hz, so saving into a bag file for 1-2 minutes was better to understand the overall performance.Thank you for the answer.